# Embed content from one part of my website to another page (responsive)

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

I am trying to take the div `#content` of server list from here (same domain): http://bans.endlessgamers.com/index.php?p=servers

And embed it on a new page (same domain): http://www.endlessgamers.com/server-list/

**The issue:** I have managed to embed it fine with `<iframe>`, but the server list is responsive and expands/collapses when clicked. When I expand, I have to scroll in the `<iframe>` window to see the content. Is there a way to force my page to expand and collapse with the information in the `<iframe>` div?

**Note:** To replicate my issue click on hostname of server to expand or collapse it.

```
<head>
<script>
$("iframe").contents().find("#content").width()
</script>
</head>

<body>
    <iframe src="http://bans.endlessgamers.com/index.php?p=servers#content"></iframe>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try set iframe height dynamic:

```
//Initially set iframe height on load
$($("#elCmsPageWrap iframe")[0]).css("height",+$("#elCmsPageWrap iframe")[0].offsetParent.clientHeight);

//Set iframe height again when collapse/expand in table
$(".listtable tbody tr td").click(function(){
    $($("#elCmsPageWrap iframe")[0]).css("height",+$("#elCmsPageWrap iframe")[0].offsetParent.clientHeight);
});
```

Comment: I tried adding that into the html, it only expanded my iframe slightly. When i expand the table, the div remains fixed. Am i doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you copy the code of the original #content div into a new file? Let's say: server-list.php

Then, you include this file on both pages:

```
<?php include 'server-list.php'; ?>
```

The include function basically pastes the code into the file.
iFrames are mostly used to embed external pages.

Comment: Yeah the file structure for sourcebans is a little odd to me. It calls to several files for server details, page template, etc. (im a novice coder). Not sure how I would go about doing that. If you or anyone can help me achieve it, that would be great. Thanks for your response.